# How to fix Header & columns in same row in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to align Table Header and columns in the same row without resizing to next line in HTML ?? anyone please help me. ?

Comment: Hi @Kiran G, Can you put some code how much you try ??

Comment: I am using normal Table only. I am uploading the file more than 50 Headers and 10000 columns. if any space between the letters its auto jumps to the next line... It looks column size big...

Comment: If I try less number of header and columns its looks very clearn.. When i try more than 15 headers and more columns. it will not in the same row.. jump to next line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we used * white-space: nowrap* it will not move to next line.

sample CSS code:

```
td, th { 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px; 
  text-align: left; 
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class "table-responsive" to the upper div of table tag. By using this when your columns are more than screen size it will start scrolling. And you won't face any issue as you described.
For more details, Refer this link --> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-responsive&stacked=h

Hope this will help you.